# Probability of being absorbed in Random walk with a single absorbing barrier

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a 1-dimensional random walk,we have a absorbing barrier at `-a`.The probability of moving to the left or right on every step is `p` and `1-p`.

My question is how to calculate the probability of being absorbed eventually if we start at the origin.

**Attempt I**

I try to imitate the solution to solve the similar question with two absorbing barrier(eg.`a` and `-a`).

In detail,let
$$p_k=P(\{\text{start at k and be absorbed at a eventually\}})$$
Obviewsly,we have $p_{-a}=0$ and $p_{a}=1$

Besides,we can draw the equation:
$$p_k=p_{k+1}*p+p_{k-1}*(1-p)$$

By this equation and initial condition above,we can attain the expression of $p_k$ and $p_0$ is what we need.

But this method is noneffective for the problem at hand because there is only one barrier,thus we only have one equation in the initial condition.

**Attempt II**

I try to simplify the question.Consider there is no barrier,we only need to start at the orign and end at `-a` with `n` steps.

It's simple to calculate such $p_n$.But some moves are invalid for our real question because they have reached `-a` before `n` steps.If we can find the number of invalid moves,which I can't resolve,we can attain $p_n'$,probability of being absorbed at `-a` right on the n_th step.Finally what we need is $\sum\limits_{n=a}^{+\infty}p_n'$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Attempt 1 is close. You can indeed leverage the two-barrier solution; instead of having the other barrier be $a$, have it be some independent quantity (say, $b$). Compute the probability of reaching $b$ before reaching $-a$; then, take a limit as $b \to \infty$.